# What method for forecasting error measuring in a poisson process?

Tags: forecasting, poisson-distribution, error, measurement-error, accuracy

There's so much different measures for the forecast error that I kind of lose the sight on which one to use. Out of the following: `MAPE`, `MSE`, `MASE`, `MAE`, `rRMSE`, `MAD`.

I know the `MAPE` isn't right to use because the value can be 0. My assumption is that the others can all be used for measuring the errors in a `Poisson process`. I know that the results of `MAD` and `MSE` can differ and that the optimal forecasting method for `MSE` will be the one with the fewest large errors, while `MAD` will have some of both small and large errors.

Question: Is there a 'best' measurement for a `Poisson process` and which one should I use? The series have `no trend` and `no seasonality`

Answer (score 1):

*Don't* use the MAD for assessing the accuracy of count data forecasts, especially not for intermittent demands. The expected MAD is minimized by the *median* of your future distribution, not its *mean*. If, say you forecast $y\sim\text{Pois}(\lambda)$ with $\lambda<\log 2$, then the median is zero... implying that you will probably get the lowest MAD by a flat zero forecast, which is badly biased and likely useless. [Here is a presentation I gave at last year's *International Symposium on Forecasting*](https://forecasters.org/wp-content/uploads/gravity_forms/7-621289a708af3e7af65a7cd487aee6eb/2015/07/Kolassa_Stephan_ISF2015.pdf) on this issue. Or look at [Morlidge (2015, Foresight)](https://ideas.repec.org/a/for/ijafaa/y2015i37p37-42.html).

I'd rather use the Mean Squared Error (MSE) or its root (RMSE) or perhaps a scaled variant. These are at least minimized by the expectation of the future distribution.

Final piece of shameless self-promotion: I have [an article in the IJF (Kolassa, 2016)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.ijforecast.2015.12.004) which looks at forecasting low volume count data (mostly intermittent), at different accuracy measures and different forecasting methods, including various flavors of Poisson models. This may be useful to you.